# libssh session connection timed out error

Tags: libssh

I've downloaded and compiled libssh 0.6.1 from [libSSH](http://www.libssh.org) .
I also linked the ssh.lib,ssh.dll to a visual c++ project .
The library with code below compiles and run fine ,
but when calling ssh_connect() , it return -1 : Timeout .
I used the option :

> ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);

to print the logging , and it says :

> ssh_connect : socket connecting now waiting for callbacks to work.
>   ssh_connect : Timeout connecting to local host.

On my laptop i installed [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) server and connecting to it using putty works .

My code, until the error :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

ssh_session my_ssh_session;
int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
int port = 22;
int rc;
char *password;
// Open session and set options
my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
    exit(-1);
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "localhost");
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
// Connect to server
rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
if (rc != SSH_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to localhost: %s\n",
        ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
    exit(-1);
}
```

This code example is copied from the [A typical SSH session Exmple](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html) site .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libssh doesn't support "localhost" as a parameter as said in the website instead , define :

```
 char* host="127.0.0.1";
```